# Can I apply for a medical e-visa to India if I already have a valid tourist visa in my passport?

Tags: visas, india, applications

I have a valid India tourist visa in my passport. Before I left India I was receiving medical treatment, and I have been told I need to go back. But when I left India recently, as I had been there for some months, the immigration agent said I shouldn't return to India straight away.

Apparently they are getting strict on people turning around. I guess it's to do with ten-year visas. Anyway, I want to continue my medical treatment, and wondered if applying for a short-term medical  e-visa would be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to predict whether you would be immediately granted a new visa allowing you to return, particularly after being advised otherwise by an immigration agent.

According to [India's visa information](https://www.indianembassy.org/pages.php?id=18):

> A ‘MEDICAL VISA’ is issued to those applicants who are traveling to India for a medical treatment in reputed / recognized hospitals / treatment centers in India for undergoing treatment in neuro-surgery, ophthalmic disorders, heart-related problems, renal disorders, organ transplantation, congenial disorders, gene-therapy, radio-therapy, joint replacement, etc.

That you were treated while in India and want to return for further care, rather that in your country of origin (or residence), may not reach the threshold necessary for a medical visa.